# Formatting axis

Tags: pgfplots

Data values of x axis in a pgfplot for latex are in thousands. I wont to use scientific notation for this axis but putting 10^n common for the axis, like

```
2.4     2.7      3.0     3.3     X10^3
```

instead of

```
2.4X10^3     2.7X10^3      3.0X10^3     3.3X10^3
```

Thanks a lot.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: @Skillmon Ok! I have retracted my close.

Comment: This should be the default as far as I understand the `pgfplots` manual. You can however do this manually with `scaled x ticks=base 10:e` or `scaled y ticks=base 10:e` or scaled z ticks=base 10:e` or (if all three should be affected) `scaled ticks=base 10:e` with `e` being the common exponent (so e.g. `scaled ticks=base 10:3`).